# SQL Server: If the beginning of the week is Monday, why is the previous Sunday included in that week?

Tags: sql-server

I'm working on a stored procedure that outputs a grid for charting.  Users can input an interval to display the chart in days, weeks, months, etc.  The data that drives this grid has a bunch of timestamps in a column called moddate.  In order to group things, I'm using:

```
DATEADD(<interval>, datediff(<interval>, 0, moddate), 0)
```

Days, Months, Quarters, and Years all work fine.  Weeks, however are including the previous Sunday.  For example, The following select statement gives me an answer of 2017-04-03:

```
select "start_of_week" = dateadd(week, datediff(week, 0, '2017-04-02 00:00:00.000'), 0);

start_of_week: 
'2017-04-03 00:00:00.000'
```

Changning @@datefirst does not affect the results.

I guess my question is twofold:

1. Why is April 2nd considered part of the week that starts with April 3rd?
2. Is there a better way to get around this than to first check for an interval of weeks, and then check every date to see if it's a Sunday and if it is, put -7 instead of 0 at the end?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Please ignore part 1.  I missed this part of the MS site: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql -    Specifying SET DATEFIRST has no effect on DATEDIFF. DATEDIFF always uses Sunday as the first day of the week to ensure the function is deterministic.  I'd still like help on the second part if possible.

Comment: Use the datediff of the day/7

Comment: Thank you.  That does work in getting the previous week, but it's not something I can apply to other intervals.  It looks like I'm going to need to run more checks and use a case statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a CASE in both the select and group by:

```
SELECT CASE
  WHEN @interval = 'week'
  THEN DATEADD(<interval>, DATEDIFF(day, 0, moddate)/7, 0)
  ELSE DATEADD(<interval>, DATEDIFF(<interval>, 0, moddate), 0)
  END as moddate,
   fullname,
   isnull(totals, 0) as totals
FROM #results
GROUP BY CASE
  WHEN @interval = 'week'
  THEN DATEADD(<interval>, DATEDIFF(day, 0, moddate)/7, 0)
  ELSE DATEADD(<interval>, DATEDIFF(<interval>, 0, moddate), 0)
  END, fullname
```

The crucial bit was using the case again in the group by.

My thanks to [ZLK](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5552667/zlk) for the /7 bit, as subtracting 7 was taking a week off of every answer.